# Passing an object to ._map in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

Below is my class with static member config.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Config} from '../shared/interfaces'

export class GlobalData {

    static config:Config = {
        appName: "",
        line: "",
    }

    constructor(private app:PApplication){
        GlobalData.config.appName = app.getData().Style? 'P_APP' : 'P_WEB'
        GlobalData.config.line = 'PApp'
    }

}
```

Below is my interface Config

```
export interface Config {
    appName: string
    line: string
}
```

I am trying to pass my static config object to below function:

```
var appConfig = this.appConfig(GlobalData.config);

appConfig = (configVariable: Config) => {
    return _.map(configVariable, function(val, key) {
        return key + "=" + val;
    }).join("&");
}
```

I am getting the below error:

> [ts] Argument of type 'Config' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'List<{}> | Dictionary<{}> | NumericDictionary<{}>'.   Type 'Config'
>   is not assignable to type 'NumericDictionary<{}>'.
>       Index signature is missing in type 'Config'.

Basically in `Javascript`, the config was a `global object`, which can be accessed in any `controller/services`.

```
var config = {appName: "", line: "" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions for the [`map` function are](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/underscore/index.d.ts#L154):

```
map<T, TResult>(
    list: _.List<T>,
    iterator: _.ListIterator<T, TResult> | _.IterateePropertyShorthand | _.IterateeMatcherShorthand<any>,
    context?: any): TResult[];

map<T, TResult>(
    object: _.Dictionary<T>,
    iterator: _.ObjectIterator<T, TResult>,
    context?: any): TResult[];
```

As you can see, the passed object should be of types `_.List<T>` or `_.Dictionary<T>`.
In your case it needs to be `_.Dictionary<T>`, which is defined like so:

```
interface Dictionary<T> extends Collection<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}
```

Your `Config` interface doesn't have an index signature which is why the compiler complains.
To get around that just cast it to `any`:

```
return _.map(configVariable as any, function(val, key) {
    return key + "=" + val;
}).join("&");
```

---

#### Edit

The signatures for [map](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/index.d.ts#L8270) in lodash are similar:

```
map<T, TResult>(
    collection: List<T>,
    iteratee?: ListIterator<T, TResult>
): TResult[];

map<T extends {}, TResult>(
    collection: Dictionary<T>,
    iteratee?: DictionaryIterator<T, TResult>
): TResult[];

map<T extends {}, TResult>(
    collection: NumericDictionary<T>,
    iteratee?: NumericDictionaryIterator<T, TResult>
): TResult[];

map<T, TResult>(
    collection: List<T>|Dictionary<T>|NumericDictionary<T>,
    iteratee?: string
): TResult[];

map<T, TObject extends {}>(
    collection: List<T>|Dictionary<T>|NumericDictionary<T>,
    iteratee?: TObject
): boolean[];
```

The [Dictionary](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/lodash/index.d.ts#L19219) is a bit different:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}
```

So it's the same problem.
As for avoiding using `any`, you can do:

```
interface Config extends _.Dictionary<string> {
    appName: string
    line: string
}
```

And then this:

```
return _.map(configVariable, function(val, key) {
    return key + "=" + val;
}).join("&");
```

Will compile with no errors.

Comment: Thanks, how to actually make it fix without passing any as the type... here

Comment: Also i am using lodash.. not underscore.js failed to update that.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks... so we should define the Dictionary right? Typescript does not provide it by default...

Comment: Sorry, it should be: `_.Dictionary<string>`. I fixed it in my answer as well